# VBA Excel Error to copy sheet in ‘Breakdown’ to ‘Macro’ and sum up holdings in each sector in each country

Tags: excel, vba

I can't build a macro in excel to copy sheet in ‘Breakdown’ to ‘Macro’ and sum up holdings in each sector in each country due to an error in code `Run-time error '13':Type mismatch`

| Ticker | Country | GICS Sector | Company Name | Market Cap.(AUD) | Portfolio Value | ISIN | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2M.AX | Australia | Consumer Staples | A2 Milk co Ltd | 3680037248 | 3320288 |  |  |
| WDS.AX | Australia | Energy | Woodside Energy | 69589179107 | 2124428 |  |  |
| NCM.AX | Australia | Materials | Newcrest Mining Ltd | 23491441330 | 4284675 |  |  |
| SPK.AX | Australia | Communication Services | Spark New Zealand Ltd | 8660063530 | 2646038 |  |  |
| CSL.AX | Australia | Health Care | CSL LTD | 128864948076 | 3353438 |  |  |
| ALD.AX | Australia | Energy | Ampol Limited | 7730520092 | 2145850 |  |  |
| SHL.AX | Australia | Health Care | Sonic Healthcare Ltd | 16685823148 | 2698623 |  |  |
| UMI.BR | Belgium | Materials | Umicore | 11110314378 | 3609592 |  |  |
| PXT.TO | Canada | Energy | Parex Resources | 3286655143 | 2417660 |  |  |
| HRMS.PA | France | Consumer Discretionary | Hermes International | 334277686218 | 107037 |  |  |
| OREP.PA | France | Consumer Staples | L'Oreal SA | 364364184439 | 2017832 |  |  |
| LEGD.PA | France | Industrials | Legrand SA | 39926734949 | 1052060 |  |  |
| 9988.HK | Hong Kong | Consumer Discretionary | Alibaba Group Holding Ltd | 348947826547 | 4938720 |  |  |
| 1882.HK | Hong Kong | Industrials | Haitian International Holdings | 5378188427 | 2941145 |  |  |
| 6690.HK | Hong Kong | Consumer Discretionary | Haier Smart Home Co Ltd | 42818299927 | 5231487 |  |  |
| 0175.HK | Hong Kong | Consumer Discretionary | Geely Automobile Holdings Lt | 18149845808 | 1681201 |  |  |
| 9696.HK | Hong Kong | Materials | Tianqi Lithium | 21536660060 | 2911998 |  |  |
| 1093.HK | Hong Kong | Health Care | CSPC Pharmaceutical Group | 14147635996 | 3102860 |  |  |
| 4516.T | Japan | Health Care | Nippon Shinyaku | 4180534466 | 3142779 |  |  |
| 7974.T | Japan | Communication Services | Nintendo Co Ltd | 88474704785 | 1555330 |  |  |
| 6971.T | Japan | Information Technology | Kyocera Corp | 30183539138 | 871812 |  |  |
| BRBY.L | UK | Consumer Discretionary | Burberry Group Plc | 16152866847 | 2546163 |  |  |
| DCC.L | UK | Industrials | DCC PLC | 8715904659 | 2736044 |  |  |
| MRK | US | Health Care | Merck & Co. Inc | 416393885829 | 2315906 |  |  |
| AMGN.O | US | Health Care | Amgen Inc | 186518277027 | 2362262 |  |  |
| MCD.N | US | Consumer Discretionary | Mcdonald'S Corp | 320831764784 | 6722295 |  |  |
| TTC | US | Industrials | Toro Co | 15785904376 | 2080889 |  |  |
| XOM | US | Energy | Exxon Mobil Corp | 624391538219 | 1681428 |  |  |

[breakdown sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF6KH.jpg)

I can't copy sheet in ‘Breakdown’ to ‘Macro’ and sum up holdings in each sector in each country.

I tried using this code from ChatGPT

```vb
Sub CopyAndSumHoldings()
    Dim breakdownSheet As Worksheet
    Dim macroSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim country As String
    Dim sector As String
    Dim holdings As Double
    Dim existingRow As Long
    
    ' Set references to sheets
    Set breakdownSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Breakdown")
    
    ' Check if "Macro" sheet exists; if not, create it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set macroSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If macroSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set macroSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        macroSheet.Name = "Macro"
    End If
    
    ' Clear existing data in Macro sheet
    macroSheet.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Find the last row in Breakdown sheet
    lastRow = breakdownSheet.Cells(breakdownSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in Breakdown sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming headers are in the first row
        ' Get country, sector, and holdings values
        country = breakdownSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        sector = breakdownSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        holdings = breakdownSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        ' Find existing row in Macro sheet for the same country and sector
        existingRow = Application.Match(country & sector, macroSheet.Range("A:A") & macroSheet.Range("B:B"), 0)
        
        ' If the combination is found, add holdings; otherwise, insert a new row
        If Not IsError(existingRow) Then
            macroSheet.Cells(existingRow, 3).Value = macroSheet.Cells(existingRow, 3).Value + holdings
        Else
            ' Find the last row in Macro sheet
            existingRow = macroSheet.Cells(macroSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ' Insert a new row in Macro sheet
            macroSheet.Cells(existingRow, 1).Value = country
            macroSheet.Cells(existingRow, 2).Value = sector
            macroSheet.Cells(existingRow, 3).Value = holdings
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `Country` and `Sector` are in column B and C on the screenshot. Why is your code loading it from columns A and B? `country = breakdownSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value         sector = breakdownSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value`. I'm not sure which column is `holdings`.

Comment: One could also use a simple pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

- The pivottable is a straightforward option for your question.
- Use Dictionary object to sum up the holdings (assumes it is in column F), if you prefert to use VBA code.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, aKey
    Dim arrData, arrRes, oSht As Worksheet
    Const HOLDING_COL = 6  ' Modify as needed
    Set oSht = Sheets("BreakDown")
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load data
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' Country | Sector
        sKey = arrData(i, 2) & "|" & arrData(i, 3)
        ' Sum up holdings
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) + arrData(i, HOLDING_COL)
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, HOLDING_COL)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(1 To objDic.Count, 1 To 3)
    i = 0
    ' Extract data from Dict
    For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
        aKey = Split(sKey, "|")
        i = i + 1
        arrRes(i, 1) = aKey(0)
        arrRes(i, 2) = aKey(1)
        arrRes(i, 3) = objDic(sKey)
    Next
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Macro").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Macro"
    ' Write output to sheet
    Range("A1:C1") = Array("Country", "GICS Sector", "Holdings")
    Range("A2").Resize(i, 3) = arrRes
    Columns(3).NumberFormatLocal = "_ * #,##0_ ;_ * -#,##0_ ;_ * ""-""??_ ;_ @_ "
    Columns("A:C").AutoFit
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a [PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) would be a solution.

If you want to use VBA for whatever reason an alternate approach would be to use SQL resp. ADODB to do the [grouping](https://skillsandautomation.com/useful-code/use-sql-group-by-in-excel-vba/) of the data

```
Option Explicit

Public Function sumData()
    
    Dim sourceFile As String
    sourceFile = "<Your filename here>"
    
    Dim sourceSheet As String
    ' The sheet with the data like in the post
    ' with header starting in A1
    sourceSheet = "Sheet1"
    
    Dim rsCon As Object, rsData As Object, szConnect As String, szSQL As String

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
    End If

    szSQL = "SELECT Country,[GICS Sector],Sum([Portfolio Value]) FROM [" & _
        sourceSheet$ & "$" & "] GROUP BY Country, [GICS Sector];"

    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    ' Write the grouped data to a new empty worksheet
    Worksheets.Add
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rsData.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsData
    
    rsData.Close: Set rsData = Nothing
    rsCon.Close: Set rsCon = Nothing

End Function
```